# jQuery id and class selector after changing class

Tags: jquery

I am new to this forum and also fairly new to jQuery so it is (as I think) a basic question but I could not find the answer and everything I tried did not work.

I have a button on a page that should do certain things and change the class. And with the new class revert those things.

This is the code:

```
    $("#info_button.buttonOff").click(function() {
    $(".content").slideUp(300, function() {
        $("#info").slideDown(300);
        $("#info").addClass("contentOn");
        $("#info_button").removeClass("buttonOff").addClass("buttonOn");
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
    });
});

$("#info_button.buttonOn").click(function() {
    $(".content").slideUp(300);
    $("#info").removeClass("contentOn");
    $("#info_button").removeClass("buttonOn").addClass("buttonOff");
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
});
```

The first event alone work. But as soon as I add the second event nothing works anymore. I think I have to do something with .unbind() but could not figure out how.

Please help.

Comment: +1 for the question. Will help people clear some concepts. Check my answer for the possible solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the jQuery collection is computed only once.

Use

```
$(document).on('click', "#info_button.buttonOff", function() {
```

and

```
$(document).on('click', "#info_button.buttonOn", function() {
```

With this, the selector will be tested everytime a click occurs.

As your element has an ID, a lighter solution could be

```
$("#info_button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('buttonOn')) {
       // do something
    } else {
       ...
```

But I'd generally prefer the first one.

Comment: Why prefer the first one? It's both harder to read and less efficient because of event delegation.

Comment: because it lets the event delegation system of jquery do the work it is intended to do and thus lets the callback code be cleaner. But I'm not saying the second one is wrong and I would use it as soon as there is some factorization possible.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. I tried it with .live first and that worked as well but buggy and I read that this is not supported in newer versions of jquery anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to test the class inside the click handler for the button:

```
$("#info_button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('buttonOff')) {
    // ...
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('buttonOn')) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
$(document).on('click', "#info_button", function() {
    $(".content").slideUp(300, function() {
        if ($("#info").is(':visible'))
            $("#info").slideUp(300);
        else
            $("#info").slideDown(300);
        $("#info").toggleClass("contentOn");
        this.toggleClass("buttonOn").toggleClass("buttonOff");
        if ($("#overlay").is(':visible'))
            $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
        else
            $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

What probably is happening is that both of your binding events are referring to the same element, so these functions would probably be interfering with each other.

You may try doing something like this:

```
$("#info_button").click(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('buttonOff') {
    $(".content").slideUp(300, function() {
        $("#info").slideDown(300);
        $("#info").addClass("contentOn");
        $("#info_button").removeClass("buttonOff").addClass("buttonOn");
        $("#overlay").fadeIn(300);
    });
} else if($(this).hasClass('buttonOn') {
$(".content").slideUp(300);
    $("#info").removeClass("contentOn");
    $("#info_button").removeClass("buttonOn").addClass("buttonOff");
    $("#overlay").fadeOut(300);
    });
}
});
```

Comment: -1 "both of your binding events are referring to the same element" : that's a wrong explanation. The problem is that one of those two initial collections is empty.